# HttpOnly and Secure not set for sub path cookie

Tags: asp.net, umbraco, httponly

I have the following in web.config...

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />
```

These settings are being applied to my site's cookies correctly except for a cookie called 'UMB_PANEL' with a path of '/umbraco'.

I have tried adding a web.config file with duplicate settings into the '/umbraco' folder but it has no effect.

How can I get these cookie settings to apply to the whole site?

Answer (score 2):

Bit late to the party with this but you can achieve what you need with [Outbound Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-outbound-rules-for-url-rewrite-module).

This will rewrite any cookies without `Secure=true` to be secure:

```
<outboundRules>
    <rule name="Add Secure Cookies" preCondition="No Secure">
      <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern=".*" negate="false"/>
      <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; Secure=true"/>
      <conditions/>
    </rule>
    <preConditions>
      <preCondition name="No Secure">
        <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="."/>
        <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="; Secure=true" negate="true"/>
      </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
  </outboundRules>
```

You can tweak the `pattern` if you need it to match a specific cookie, e.g: `^(UMB_PANEL).*`

Answer (score 1):

I believe that cookie only is set if you log in to the Umbraco admin area.

http://our.umbraco.org/forum/using/ui-questions/20674-Does-Umbraco-make-use-of-Cookies-anywhere-in-the-core-product

My guess is that your main web site users would never get that cookie.  I realize that isn't directly answering the question, but perhaps it makes it a moot point?

Comment: Afraid not, client still thinks its an issue.